# How to optimize drawing& intersection of thousands of cubes in THREE.js?

Tags: javascript, performance, three.js, webgl

I'm having a 3d model viewer/editor and I'm offering users to select parts of the object (areas). I display cubes on all the selected areas offering users to click the points and edit them.

Rendering more than cca 500 cubes starts lagging the editor.

This is what i am having:

```
for(var pp in points)          {                                                       
var cube = new THREE.Mesh( new THREE.CubeGeometry( 1, 1, 1 ), new  THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x000000}) );
        cube.position.x = model.points[points[pp]].x;
        cube.position.y = model.points[points[pp]].y;
        cube.position.z = model.points[points[pp]].z;
        cube.userData.pointCube = true;
        scene.add( cube );
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions on how to draw this faster.
Note: I need to track cubes intersections. Currently working smooth for ~~100 cubes.

Comment: Well in some circumstances drawing to an in memory area (a hidden canvas in that case) and then drawing that area to a displayed area in one shot usually makes things faster, but i'm not sure it applies to the canvas and i don't know if you can do that since the canvas might be encapsulated in the library you're using.

Comment: Have you checked the octtree example and the octtree raycasting examples for optimizing your picking/intersection tests? 
Also, depends on what you want to do with your cubes. You could use Three.BufferGeometry and BufferGeometryUtils to "group" them together and have faster drawing.